# Modelling latent variables: lavaan warning: covariance matrix of latent variables is not positive definite

Tags: covariance-matrix, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I have 3 independent variables (linguistic, onk2_sc3 and dsk2_sc3) and one dependent variable (Reading) in SEM multigroups (3 groups) comparison:

```r
model1 <- '
linguistic =~ grk1_sc3 + vok1_sc3 
Reading ~ linguistic + onk2_sc3 + dsk2_sc3   
linguistic ~~ onk2_sc3
dsk2_sc3 ~~ linguistic
dsk2_sc3 ~~ onk2_sc3
'
```

Unlike linguistic with 2 indicators, other variables were previously not latent modelled. My coauthors suggested to model the other 3 variables (dsk2_sc3, onk2_sc3 and Reading) as latent as well. One coauthor suggested following model:

```
model_latent <- '
linguistic =~ grk1_sc3 + vok1_sc3 
pw =~ 1*dsk2_sc3
dsk2_sc3 ~~ 0.54*dsk2_sc3
pa =~ 1*onk2_sc3
onk2_sc3 ~~ 1.68*onk2_sc3
reading =~ 1*Reading
Reading ~~ 0.21*Reading
reading ~ linguistic + pa + pw  
linguistic ~~ pw
linguistic ~~ pa
pw ~~ pa
'
```

when I run: `fit_model_latent <- sem(model_latent, data=data1, group = "Language")` and got following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.
2: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables
                is not positive definite in group 1;
                use lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv") to investigate.
3: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables
                is not positive definite in group 2;
                use lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv") to investigate.
4: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables
                is not positive definite in group 3;
                use lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv") to investigate.
5: In lavaan::lavaan(model = model_latent, data = data1, group = "Language",  :
  lavaan WARNING: not all elements of the gradient are (near) zero;
                  the optimizer may not have found a local solution;
                  use lavInspect(fit, "optim.gradient") to investigate
```

I run lavInspect(fit, cov.lv) and got following result:

```
$`1`
           lngstc pw     pa     readng
linguistic  6.508                     
pw          3.997  3.338              
pa          7.975  2.670 15.296       
reading     2.779  0.820  1.919  1.491

$`2`
           lngstc pw     pa     readng
linguistic  3.648                     
pw          2.457  2.418              
pa          4.999  1.015 13.906       
reading     2.060  0.471  1.134  1.196

$`3`
           lngstc pw     pa     readng
linguistic 18.043                     
pw          5.447  3.342              
pa         14.031  2.361 12.928       
reading     4.379  0.695  1.939  1.624
```

I was confuse because I cannot see any negative values in that output.

To clarify this post:
With this long post, I basically have two questions:

1. do I misunderstood the warning from lavaan: covariance matrix of latent variables are not positive definite (already answered by @mdewey, thanks!)
2. how to get rid off the lavaan warnings. This question, as already mentioned by @Peter Flom is not really the topic for this forum. I must admit, I did not really check the topic regulation. Should I delete this post and move it to another forum?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you may need to read more about what positive definite means.

Comment: Hi @mdewey, thanks for the comment. just one short question though: do you see any "problems" in the latent model?

Comment: I am not an expert in lavaan so cannot even say what your model is, nevermind whether it is OK.

Comment: Your model isn't identified. Read up on identification in SEM.

Comment: If your question is about lavaan, it is off topic.  If it is about statistics, then it is on topic.  Can you clarify (in your post, not just in a reply) which it is?